# ReactJS while passing function from parent to child and accessing parent state not returning completely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I was trying to access Parent state when a function is called from Child component, for that created a function in Parent component and passed it to Child, issue is I am not able to access the state completely.
for example on button click I add a new input field and a delete button, suppose I added 10 input fields, and added all of them in state array, but when i click delete button of second input field, the count I get from state is 1, similar if I click 5th delete button i get count as 4 and it only show me 4 items in state, but it has 10 items
Here is an example link https://codesandbox.io/s/add-react-component-onclick-forked-t2i0ll?file=/src/index.js:0-869

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Input = ({ deleteRow, position }) => {
  const handleDelete = () => deleteRow(position);
  return (
    <>
      <input placeholder="Your input here" />
      <button onClick={handleDelete}>Delete</button>
    </>
  );
};

const Form = () => {
  const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([]);

  const onDeleteRow = (position) => {
    console.log("inputCount", inputList);
  };
  const onAddBtnClick = (event) => {
    setInputList(
      inputList.concat(
        <Input
          key={inputList.length}
          position={inputList.length}
          deleteRow={onDeleteRow}
        />
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onAddBtnClick}>Add input</button>
      {inputList}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.getElementById("form"));
```

Answer (score 2):

It's called **a stale closure**.

You can avoid that by not storing react elements inside the state.

Example:

```
const Form = () => {
  const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([]);

  const onDeleteRow = (position) => {
    console.log("inputCount", inputList);
  };
  const onAddBtnClick = (event) => {
    setInputList([...inputList, inputList.length])
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onAddBtnClick}>Add input</button>
      {inputList.map(item => (
        <Input
          key={item}
          position={item}
          deleteRow={onDeleteRow}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to re-render the list, then the delete must operate within the context of setInputList call with reference to prevState.

```
    const onDeleteRow = (position) => {
      console.log("inputCount", inputList);
      setInputList((prevState) => {
        console.log("input list", prevState)
        return // updated list
      });
    };
```

Also watchout:

Your key reference is only valid if none of the items gets deleted and then subsequently added.  This is essentially the index of the item.  So the index is reference for position will also get out of synch. Konrad's answers some of these issues by changing the key and position to the value of whatever input you will be adding.  Then you will just need to filter the inputList for everything but that particular input value.  Otherwise, you will need to manage the list more closely.